# How to have certain files in certain paths automatically after installation of the Debian (server)?

Tags: debian, iso, simple-cdd

I have been requested to make an installation ISO for the Debian server such that:

1. Certain packages need to be pre-installed on it.
2. Certain files (mostly Python modules) need to be located in certain directories automatically.

ISOs are given to customers and these conditions are there for removing the need for any other actions by them after the installation.

Currently, I have achieved the first condition by using [Simple-CDD](https://wiki.debian.org/Simple-CDD/Howto); however, for the second one, I don't know how I can achieve it. (One thing that is mentioned in the Simple-CDD HOWTO page is that files needed could be listed in the profiles/NAME.extra *so that they will be added to the /simple-cdd in the ISO file*, but I need those files in the filesystem of the Debian itself after it is installed).

Comment: Also interested.  After a week of working on this a couple of years ago (vanilla CD, +non-free, and a few custom packages), I hired a consultant who spent two weeks with no success.  If I were to do this again, I'd probably try to hire a maintainer of Simple-CDD or a member of the DebianInstaller team or ask on one of their mailing lists.

Comment: For the second part of this, you could create a custom debian package which deploys all of the files you need.  For something simple like this, I'd put your custom files into a directory (preserving directory structure) and use `cmake` and `cpack` to build a `*.deb` out of it.  Then your `CMakeLists.txt` just needs a simple `install(DIRECTORY` command.

Comment: Thank you, can you please give me a link to a guide on what you have just said? Honestly I've not used cmake so far :) (although I've heard about it a lot).

Comment: I'll write an answer.  Give me a few minutes

Comment: You shouldn't normally need to deploy python modules. Debian has a good collection of published python modules in `python3-*` packages.

Comment: I see but some of these packages are not from Python's standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question #2, you could create a `*.deb` package and include that in Simple-CDD.  If prefer this over simply deploying files or generating them with a script because the files are "owned" by a package.  That means you can `dpkg -S $file` and understand why they are present.

> Note: Consider updating this answer with instructions on how to add a `*.deb` package to Simple-CDD

The native way to set this up would be with `dh_make`, but I find `cpack` easier for trivial cases like simple file deployment like this.

1. Collect the files you'll want to deploy into a directory.  I suggest preserving directory structure.  I'll do all of this relative to `.` so if you want to deploy `/etc/myconfig`, copy it to `./etc/myconfig`.
2. Create `./CMakeLists.txt` with the following content:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(foo)

# Repeat this for each directory or file you want to install
install(DIRECTORY etc 
  DESTINATION /
  USE_SOURCE_PERMISSIONS
  COMPONENT default
)

set(CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME foo)
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION "Long description of what this package is"
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY "Short description")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR "The ones who installed your OS")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_CONTACT "yourname@yourorg.com")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0")

set(CPACK_COMPONENT_ALL default)
set(CPACK_DEB_COMPONENT_INSTALL "ON")

include(CPack)
```

> Note: In Debian stretch and earlier, `cpack` had a bug where it would only generate md5sums for a component install.  This broke some tools like `debsums`.  That's the only reason I'm using `COMPONENT` here. This bug was fixed in Buster.  If you are using buster or later, you can delete any line with `COMPONENT` in it.

3. Build your package

```
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake ..
$ cpack
```

You'll find a `*.deb` file sitting in your build directory.  That's what you'll want to include in your Simple-CDD.

4. Verify your package

Run this:

```
$ dpkg --contents *.deb
```

You should see all of the files you want included.  The size should also make sense.  You can also consider installing that with `dpkg -i *.deb` then look in your target locations to ensure that things look ok.

Comment: Wow, that would be an amazing adventure since I've not done this before. I'll try it and will mark this as the accepted answer after I've done it. And yes I'm using Buster. Thanks a ton.

Comment: I've created the deb file successfully(when I install it the files in it go to correct paths), however, I cannot make simple-cdd to work properly... I've put my deb file in a directory called `debs` in the root directory of my simple-cdd project, then I've tried multiple forms of the command suggested in the HowTo, e.g.: `build-simple-cdd  --profiles NAME --local-packages debs` and `build-simple-cdd --profiles NAME --local-packages ./debs/mypackages.deb`. I also have this file: `./profiles/NAME.conf` which has this line in it(again, according to the HowTo): `mirror_components="main non-free"`.

Comment: This is where I got stuck a few years ago too.

Answer (score 1):

You identified how to ship extra files on the CD with Simple-CDD; now you can ship an archive of some sort (or even a proper package) and unpack it into `/target` using a [preseed file](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/apb.en.html) with a [post-installation script](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/apbs05.en.html#preseed-hooks) to put them in the right place.

You don't need to preseed every option, just the ones you want to take away from the user doing the installation.

Comment: I'm not sure if I quite understand this is answering which one of the needs listed in my question, but I don't have any problem with including packages, I've done it and it has worked, but my problem is with the second part, I need some files (which are not packages) to be pre-added to the files of the Debian after it's installed. Can you please make it clear if your answer covers this as well? Thank you.

Comment: The installer can deal with **both** your needs. For the extra files, ship them as an archive and unpack them in the post-installation script. I clarified the answer.

Comment: I'm afraid I've tried that without success. I first archived the files, then listed the name of the archive file in the NAME.extra and then wrote a post-installation-script to move it to the desired destination and uncompress it and etc... but, it didn't work. Initially I thought the archive will be in the /simple-cdd of the Debian, BUT as it turns out, it will be _added to the iso_. So the main problem is I don't know where that archive will be accessible from the script. What would be its path? (Thank you again, I'll upvote but not choose it as the answer yet).

Comment: In a plain CD with D-I the CD is the root directory for the installer and the destination is `/target` (e.g. `/target/etc`). I'm not familiar enough with Simple-CDD to know if it mucks around with that, but get a shell in the installer and you can have a look around.